# Where can i get font awesome fruits and vegetables icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, glyphicons

I have been searching for the font awesome icons for fruits and vegetables. but i couldn't get the appropriate solution. where can i get those icons? can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to use icons I usually go to 
[iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=fruit)

They have a lot of cool icons there, and I checked the fruit stuff for you and they sure have lots of it!

Good luck!

edit: 
Try this: apple - [github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2979](http://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2979) 
Lots more: [github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/labels/food%20icons](http://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/labels/food%20icons)

[image]

Comment: thanx, anything is there in font awesome icons?

Comment: Try this: apple -  https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2979

lost more: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/labels/food%20icons